# Haml - how to put ruby variable into the name of class identifier

Tags: ruby, class, syntax, haml

This is a line, which I use for formatting my links:

```
%a.accordion-toggle.toggle-6{:href => "#"} #{name}
```

I would need to have an option to put in this class **toggle-6** my own digit, for example **toggle-1** etc.

How to do that in HAML syntax? I've tried something like

```
%a.accordion-toggle.toggle-#{id}{:href => "#collapseOne"} #{name}
```

But this returns

```
Illegal element: classes and ids must have values.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can specify dynamic values as attributes:

```
%a{class: "accordion-toggle toggle-#{id}", href: "#collapseOne"} #{name}
```